# jQuery load the first ten elements with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

The page I'm trying to load is something like this (although, the number of paragraphs with the class "text" is different every time):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
<p class="text">1</p>
<p class="text">2</p>
<p class="text">3</p>
<p class="text">4</p>
<p class="text">5</p>
<p class="text">6</p>
<p class="text">7</p>
<p class="text">8</p>
<p class="text">9</p>
<p class="text">10</p>
<p class="text">11</p>
<p class="text">12</p>
<p class="text">13</p>
<p class="text">14</p>
<p class="text">15</p>
<p class="text">16</p>
<p class="text">17</p>
<p class="text">18</p>
<p class="text">19</p>
<p class="text">20</p>
<p class="sometext">Some other text here</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to load only the first ten paragraphs with jQuery with something like `$('#text').load('other_file.html #container .p');`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector. It's 0-based so `p:lt(10)` should load the first 10 `p` elements.

```
$('#text').load('other_file.html #container p:lt(10)');
```

Keep in mind the whole response is still being downloaded, only a subsection is displayed via the selector.

Comment: How can I use this to load the next 10, so from 10-20?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use the [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector:

```
$('#text').load('other_file.html #container p:lt(10)');
```

Answer (score 2):

try using the `:lt()` selector

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

```
$('#text').load('other_file.html #container p:lt(10)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS3-style selector to only load the first 10 elements:

```
$('#text').load('other_file.html #container .p:nth-child(-n+10)');
```

This will load the first 10 `p` elements within the `#container` element.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ (Note that `nth-child` starts at one, not zero)